# Adding Data tables to line charts with Python PPTX

Tags: python-pptx

I've received a request to create line charts that include automatically-generated data tables with the legend. This is currently possible in PowerPoint:

[image: PowerPoint Screenshot]
[image: PowerPoint Chart]

Scanny confirmed this isn't supported, so now I'm trying to insert the XML directly. Here's what I need to insert:

```
<c:dTable><c:showHorzBorder val="1"/><c:showVertBorder val="1"/><c:showOutline val="1"/><c:showKeys val="1"/></c:dTable>
```

It falls right before the closing tag </c:plotArea>. I've figured out how to edit XML on more granular details, but inserting a new thing in this location is something new.

Comment: Nope, you didn't miss anything. There is no API support for this yet.

Comment: Hi scanny! I changed the original post to reflect that there's no API support. My lack of knowledge is my problem, but I'm hopeful someone has tried to so something similar.

Comment: To edit XML directly I highly suggest you to use a library called "BeautifulSoap", and you need to add a parser for XML. (In the official documentation there is a very user friendly how to).

Then you proceed to manipulate the xml file as a 'beautifulsoap object', and then replaces your target xml.

Comment: Hi Roni! 
Is there are reason BeautifulSoup is a better option than Pythonpptx's XMLchemy for a relatively small edit? (Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm as yet clueless about editing XML using Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some extensive searching, I found a [question about changing the size of the plot area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204792/is-it-possible-to-alter-the-plot-area-size-of-a-chart-using-python-pptx), which is accessing XML in the ballpark of what I was looking for. This helped be better understand what I needed to do. Based on that solution, I added the following to my code which works when called!

Defining chart:

```
graphic_frame = placeholder.insert_chart(v.charttypelist[intendedchart], chart_data)
chart = graphic_frame.chart
```

The method:

```
def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
    element = OxmlElement(tagname)
    element.attrib.update(kwargs)
    parent.append(element)
    return element

def add_table_line_graph(chart):
    plotArea = chart._element.chart.plotArea
    SubElement(plotArea, 'c:dTable') # Add data table tag
    dataTable = chart._element.chart.plotArea.dTable
    # Add values to data table tag
    for sub in ['c:showHorzBorder', 'c:showVertBorder', 'c:showOutline', 'c:showKeys']:
        SubElement(dataTable, sub, val='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to consider using COM then you could have a template pptx with the Chart where the data table is already enabled in the legend. Then it would simply be a matter of substituting the data and the legend will update itself when you re-fresh the chart.  Updating the xml seems like a daunting task to me :). Alternatively (you stil need a template with the chart where the option for legend with data table is enabled-> you can substitute the data in python-pptx but then I am almost sure you need to do a chart refresh in order for the legend to be updated)

Comment: This is an interesting prospect, but this situation is one mini-module among a thousand, so I'd have to completely restructure how I'm handling projects—a much more daunting task. Additionally, when line graphs weren't needed, I'd have to manually delete those slides—also daunting for my current scale.

Comment: yeah that is just what I would do. But your situation I guess is different. If you make the xml manipulation, pls post it here it would be interesting to see how much effort it took.I am not sure what you mean by manually deleting. You can delete slides/object both in com and python-pptx.

Comment: Thanks, Atanas! I posted the solution that worked for me below.